# Pass parameters from ConfirmNavigationRequest to NavigationService in Prism

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, navigation, prism

*I have a viewmodel that implements `IConfirmNavigationRequest` and [I need to pass information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#sec10) from this viewmodel to a navigation broker class that I have, which is not coupled to any specific views or viewmodels.*

Instead the navigation broker class has access to the `IRegion` of interest as well as to the `IRegionNavigationService`.

#### ViewModel Adding Parameters to Uri

```
    public override void ConfirmNavigationRequest(NavigationContext navigationContext,
                                                  Action<bool> continuationCallback)
    {
        _verificationCount++;
        navigationContext.Parameters.Add("Count", _verificationCount.ToString());
        continuationCallback(Verify());
    }
```

#### A Navigation Broker that Needs To Access the Passed Parameters

```
    // Some method
    _region.RequestNavigate(new Uri(_nextView, UriKind.Relative), NavigationCallback);

    private void NavigationCallback(NavigationResult navigationResult)
    {            
        if (navigationResult.Error == null)
        {
            if (navigationResult.Result == true)
            {
                // Need to evaluate the Count argument here
                // int count = ...
                // if (count < 5)
                QueueNextView();                     
            } else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Navigation Cancelled");
            }
        }
        else
        {
             Debug.WriteLine("Navigation Error");                
        }
    }
```

#### How to Access Parameter Through Region or NavigationService, Outside ViewModel?

- I cannot find a way to access `NavigationContext` through `NavigationService` or `Region`?
- I also tried this `_region.NavigationService.Journal.CurrentEntry.Uri.OriginalString` but it did not show any query information, just the registered View string name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agustin Adami [provided the answer here](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/discussions/357297):

```
navigationResult.Context.Parameters["Count"];
```